# ViewDoesNotExist at / Could not import django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to. Parent module django.views.generic.simple does not exist

Tags: django, view

I am new to django framework. Please help me through this.

when i run python manage.py runserver, i am facing an error,

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /

Could not import django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to. Parent module    django.views.generic.simple does not exist.
```

my project name is scrapboard, my app name is core.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Also, welcome to the Django tag, have you read the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/)? We need some more information about your current problem in order to help you better.

Comment: We can help you only with sufficient facts. So provide us with proper code of your `urls.py` and `views.py`. Then we will sure find a solution for your problem

Answer (score 3):

I realise this question is two years old, but I also hit this while upgrading an old project. The url structure

```
url(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': 'whatever' }),
```

Was removed and replaced with;

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/whatever'),permanent=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is clear. That module does not exist. That is because it was deprecated and removed two versions ago. You should follow the correct  documentation for the version of Django you are using.